# How to give effect in body but not for particular div using jQuery

Tags: html, css, blur, css-filters

I have one page and in this, I have toggle menu. When I open menu, the whole body gets blurred but I don't want the menu to be blurred.

I have tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("blur-body")
    $(".menu-ul").slideToggle("slow")
  });
});
```

```css
.blur-body {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.menu-ul {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<span>This is a another paragraph.</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<button>Menu</button>
<ul class="menu-ul">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>111</li>
  <li>1111</li>
  <li>11111</li>
</ul>
```

> **Note:** This is only a demo. The full website has a lot more content compared to this.

Comment: What do you mean by blur body? Do you have some background image or something on the body which you want to be blurred? Or are you saying only the menu should not be blurred but the `p`, `span` can be blurred?

Comment: blur body means, ALL the content of body. Image, tag, all.

Comment: Ok, but you want the menu alone to be not blurred?

Comment: ya. exactly . I want all content blur using -webkit-filter:blur(3px); but menu remains not blured.

Comment: You'll probably need to enclose the content to be blurred in a div.

Comment: @ShurvirMori: Ok, I have added an answer. Check and let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this, in your existing code.

```
.blur-body,.blur-body *:not(.menu-ul) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> When I open menu, Whole body gets, blured but, I dont want menu Blur.

My understanding based on the above statement is that you want all parts of the page (or body) other than the menu to be blurred. For this, you can use the `not` selector and then apply the blur only to the child elements that do not have `class='menu-ul'`. This would mean that the menu itself would not be blurred.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("blur-body")
    $(".menu-ul").slideToggle("slow")
  });
});
```

```css
.blur-body >:not(.menu-ul) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.menu-ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<span>This is a another paragraph.</span>
<div>Some extra content to mimick a page.
  <div>Some other extra content</div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<button>Menu</button>
<ul class="menu-ul">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>111</li>
  <li>1111</li>
  <li>11111</li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want the menu button also to be not blurred, then add an extra class to the `button` element like in the below snippet and use the attribute selector along with the `:not` instead of a class selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("blur-body")
    $(".menu-ul").slideToggle("slow")
  });
});
```

```css
.blur-body > *:not([class^='menu-']) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.menu-ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<span>This is a another paragraph.</span>
<div>Some extra content to mimick a page.
  <div>Some other extra content</div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<button class='menu-btn'>Menu</button>
<ul class="menu-ul">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>111</li>
  <li>1111</li>
  <li>11111</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ShurvirMori: Glad that it helped. I've also added another snippet where the button is also not blurred (just in case you need it).

Comment: #Harry : Ya, Its Ok. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like following way. Select all child element of body except menu.

```
("body *").not('.menu-ul, .menu-ul > li').toggleClass("blur-body")
```

Following is the working snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("body *").not('.menu-ul, .menu-ul > li').toggleClass("blur-body")
       $(".menu-ul").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});
```

```css
.blur-body{
   -webkit-filter:blur(5px);
   filter:blur(5px);
}
.menu-ul{display:none}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<span>This is a another paragraph.</span><br/><br/>
<button>Menu</button>
<ul class="menu-ul">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>11</li>
   <li>111</li>
   <li>1111</li>
   <li>11111</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You toggled the body. That was the problem you just needed to toggle the class .menu-ul

You did in your click function:

```
$("body").toggleClass("blur-body")
```

but if you only want menu do this:

```
$(".menu-ul").toggleClass("blur-body")
```

Here is the full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".menu-ul").toggleClass("blur-body")
        $(".menu-ul").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});
```

```css
.blur-body{
   -webkit-filter:blur(5px);
   filter:blur(5px);
}
.menu-ul{display:none}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<span>This is a another paragraph.</span><br/><br/>
<button>Menu</button>
<ul class="menu-ul">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>11</li>
   <li>111</li>
   <li>1111</li>
   <li>11111</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your JS like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".menu-ul").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});
```

Now it works